# Lag in an infinite scrolling image gallery (CSS)

Tags: html, css, scroll, image-gallery

I'm trying to do an infinite scrolling image gallery based on [**this**](https://designshack.net/articles/css/infinitephotobanner/) code (credits).
 For some reason, there's a lag after the last image scrolls (the first picture that is supposed to show up doesn't show up until 5 seconds after the last image disappears) and I'm not sure why. 
I want to know what's wrong and how I can fix this (make the first image appear  beside the last image as soon as it scrolls.)

Here's what the CSS code looks like:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;} 
body {
    background: url('dark_geometric.png');
}
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: white;
}
/*photobanner*/
.photobanner {
    height: 233px;
    width: 3550px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }
}
@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }
}
@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }
}
.photobanner {
    height: 233px;
    width: 3550px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    font-size: 0
}
.photobanner img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.photobanner img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

And here's a bit of the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <ul id="scroller">
          <li><img class="first" src="/artsu/001.jpg" alt="" /></li>
          <li><img src="/artsu/002.jpg" alt="" /></li>
          <li><img src="/artsu/003.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only things I added to the CSS are the img tag (to keep img size consistent) and li tag (to make the images horizontal) in the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes are working fine, it's just that you need to change the `class` assigning of tag from `img` (i.e. `.first`) to assigning that to `first li tag`, this makes your `animation` works.

But it's you who need to `calculate` the `timing` to get expected output.

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
body {
   background: url('dark_geometric.png');
   overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
}
 /*photobanner*/

 .photobanner {
   height: 233px;
   width: 1100px;
   margin-bottom: 80px;
 }

 ul > li {
   display: inline-block;
 }

 li.first {
   -webkit-animation: bannermove 8s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: bannermove 8s linear infinite;
   -ms-animation: bannermove 8s linear infinite;
   -o-animation: bannermove 8s linear infinite;
   animation: bannermove 8s linear infinite;
 }

 @keyframes bannermove {
   0% {
     margin-left: 0px;
   }
   100% {
     margin-left: -450px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="photobanner">
    <ul id="scroller">
      <li class="first"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/111/fff" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/f33/111" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/2f2/111" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And even change the display of li tag to inline-block.

Comment: thank you! Where/how can I calculate the timing? (which tag)?

Comment: Welcome :-) I mean animation-duration as in above code is 8s. Change that to get same effect as in that post.